# What is a "24 hours burn in test"?

Tags: display

I saw a used LED Monitor for sale and they said that they performed a "24 hours burn in test."  What does that mean, or more specifically what does it mean that a monitor passed this test?  I Googled it and found some software and different discussions about it but I'm still not sure what to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**24 hours burn in test** has no proper definition for monitors. It could pretty much refer to anything from using the monitor for 24 hours and verifying that it didn't die in the meantime to using a tool like [CheckeMON](http://www.ykwong.com/checkemon.html) and actually performing a number of tests (colors, convergence, interference, power supply, etc.).

Unless there's *at least some* information available (e.g., on the manufacturer's website), I suggest disregarding it as a marketing technique. Early failures are covered by the warranty anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Generally a burn in test of any type means to subject the piece of equipment to either normal or abnormal conditions for an extended period of time, typically to prove the functionality of the device in question.  I would expect a second hand monitor to be given a 24 hour test to prove that the power supply is not faulty or to detect dead pixels.

Similarly a CPU burn in test generally subjects the computer to heavy load for an extended period in order to prove that the system is stable and does not have overheating problems.

Answer (score 1):

A [burn-in test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn-in) simply means that the acquired product have been tested by the manufacturer before it is package to the seller or the store:

> **Burn-in is the process by which components of a system are exercised
>   prior to being placed in service (and often, prior to the system being
>   completely assembled from those components).**
>
> **The intention is to detect those particular components that would fail
>   as a result of the initial, high-failure rate portion of the bathtub
>   curve of component reliability. If the burn-in period is made
>   sufficiently long (and, perhaps, artificially stressful), the system
>   can then be trusted to be mostly free of further early failures once
>   the burn-in process is complete.**
>
> A precondition for a successful burn-in is a bathtub-like failure
>   rate, that is, there are noticeable early failures with a decreasing
>   failure rate following that period. By stressing all devices for a
>   certain burn-in time the devices with the highest failure rate fail
>   first and can be taken out of the cohort. The devices that survive the
>   stress have a later position in the bathtub curve (with an
>   appropriately lower ongoing failure rate).
>
> Thus by applying a burn-in, early in-use system failures can be
>   avoided at the expense (tradeoff) of a reduced yield caused by the
>   burn-in process.
>
> When the equivalent lifetime of the stress is extended into the
>   increasing part of the bathtub-like failure-rate curve, the effect of
>   the burn-in is a reduction of product lifetime. In a mature production
>   it is not easy to determine whether there is a decreasing failure
>   rate. To determine the failure time distribution for a very low
>   percentage of the production, one would have to destroy a very large
>   number of devices.
>
> When possible, it is better to eliminate the root cause of early
>   failures than doing a burn-in. Because of this, a process that
>   initially uses burn-in may eventually phase it out as the various root
>   causes for failures are identified and eliminated.
>
> For electronic components, burn-in is frequently conducted at elevated
>   temperature and perhaps elevated voltage. This process may also be
>   called heat soaking. The components may be under continuous test or
>   simply tested at the end of the burn-in period.
>
> There is another use of the term by some audiophiles, who leave new
>   audio equipment turned on for multiple days or weeks, to get the
>   components to achieve optimal performance. However, many debates have
>   arisen about the benefits of this practice.

On your specific case it means your monitor have been tested for 24 hours before it been packaged.